# how to retrieve limited number of related model and sort collection by related model in laravel?

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-6

I have 3 model
**Shop** model, **Product** model, **Picture** model

I want to retrieve a collection of shops with last 3 Product model with their pictures and sort my collection based on newest product.
I tried `leftjoint` and `joint` in **laravel 6** to be able to sort the result but i get all shops`product (i only need last 3 product for each shop),

when I use joint I cant retrieve product pictures 
I also have tried “`with`” method in laravel  , I couldnt sort the result based on `product.creatred`_at and also i get all related product in this method too.(as i mentioned i need the last 3 product)

```
class Shop extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{

    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
    }

    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\hPicture', 'pictureable');
    }

}


Shop::select('shops.*', 'products.id', 'products.shop_id', 'products.name as pname', 'products.user_id', 'products.code', 'products.price')
            ->with(['pictures', 'products.pictures'])
            ->leftjoin('products', function ($leftJoin) {
                $leftJoin->on('shops.id', '=', 'products.shop_id');
            });
            $dataList = $dataList->orderBy($field, $order);
            $dataList = $dataList->paginate(5)->appends(['sortField' => $field, 'sortOrder' => $order]);
```

the table layout for product and shop model is:

```
 Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();  
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->uuid('uuid');
    });
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->uuid('uuid');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 ways of resolving this:

1. Either you pull in all products, and trim them in the end(advisable only if not too many products per shop):

```
$shops = Shop::with(['products' => function($subQuery) { 
    $subQuery
        ->with('pictures') //Running in scope of product, also load each product's pictures
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])
->get();
foreach ($shops as $shop) {
   $shop->setRelation('products', $shop->products->take(3));
}
```

NOTE:

You will load every single product that is linked to the shops you load. You could get memory issues with this.

2. Take only what you need, but introduce a n+1 query issue(advisable only with small quantities of `$shops`:

```
$shops = Shop::get();
foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    $shop->load([
        'products' => function($query) {
            $query
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->limit(3)
                ->get();
    }]);
}
```

NOTE:

N+1 query problem: You are performing a new query for each shop, so if you have a million shops, it will be a million extra queries.

EDIT: (answering comment question)

Q: How can i sort $shops based on their latest product created_at field?

```
$sortedShops = $shops->sortBy(function ($shop, $key) {
    return $shop->products->first()->created_at;
})->values()->all();
```

`sortBy` is called on the collection(not uery). It allows you to go over each element(in this case shops) and use each object. Please do note that this function will fail if you have no products linked to the shop.

The `->values()->all()` at the end makes sure that when you convert your shops to json, you will create an array, and not an object in js.

Source:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby

EDIT: (deleted original answer as it did not work)

- Previous answer does not work, because `limit(3)` will limit the total amound of products loaded, in stead of 3 products per shop(my bad).

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if it works ;) Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: in fact I think I need the latest created_at field of the last related product for each shop to be able to sort based on that data

Comment: Depends on your table-layout.Could you post which columns are in which tables? Then I can try to spot the better answer with you :)

Comment: i edit the question . I want $shops sort by  their latest product created_at filed

Comment: @Mostafa, I updated the answer, let me know if it works :)

Comment: sorry . the first part   ->limit(3)   return the last 3 products in product table not for each shop model

Comment: Good point, I will look into that, didn't notice it with my test

Comment: I've looked around but found no solution to this, except for handling it in a loop, which offcourse is an n+1 query. I'll update my answer, with a small sidenote.